# Retrieving String From Java Class

Tags: java, android, string

I am fairly new to java / android programming and have mostly been following tutorials / reading. I have 2 classes called MainActivity and Homeactivity, the MainActivity is where the user logs in and HomePageactivity is opened via intent if the login is correct.

The username is passed through an edit text to which i have used the following code in the main class

```
String CurrentUser = editTextusername.getText().toString();
public String GetCurrentUser ()
{
    return CurrentUser;
}
```

And this in the homepage class

```
MainActivity testing = new MainActivity();
String x = testing.GetCurrentUser();
CurrentUserName.setText(x);
```

This seems like it should work to me, how ever when launching my application it just crashes, and without the lines of code in the main activity it works fine

Any ideas as to what im doing wrong here guys

Comment: **MainActivity testing = new MainActivity();** this is not how android should work...

Comment: I think your problem is editTextusername doesn't have text when you assign CurrentUser and toString on null throws a null pointer

Comment: Did you read the log messages?

Answer (score 0):

You can use intent to carry info from one `Activity` to another. 
Read this: [Intents](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters.html)

It is quite easy to transfer strings and primitive data types via intent, using `putExtra()` . 
Some example code to make it more clear:

```
//this runs, for example, after a button click
Intent intent = new Intent(this,SecondActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("username", userName);
startActivity(intent);
```

At the other end you can take them as like this:

```
String username = getIntent().getStringExtra("username");
```

Answer (score 0):

The String may be null during setting to TextView check before setting to textView

```
String CurrentUser = editTextusername.getText().toString();
                            public String GetCurrentUser ()
                            {
                               if(currentUser.length>0&&currentUser!="")      
                                return CurrentUser;
                               else return "empty";  
                            }
String x = testing.GetCurrentUser();

         CurrentUserName.setText(""+x);
```